# Why am I getting back the same Bitmap even after compressed?

Tags: c#, xamarin, bitmap

I have the following code trying to compress a bitmap and use it for uploading.

```
    Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageFileByte, 0, imageFileByte.Length);
    byte[] compressedData = null;
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
         bitmap1.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 50, stream);
         compressedData = stream.ToArray();
    }

    //load compressed bitmap from memory
    using (var anotherStream = new MemoryStream(compressedData))
    {
         var compressedBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(anotherStream);
    }
```

When I debug, `bitmap1` on line 1 shows `3021330` bytes, when come to the `compressedData` on line 6, it did shrink to `70128` bytes.

Now I want to convert again the `compressedData` to a bitmap again since it is a byte array but not a bitmap, when it comes to line 11, the `compressedBitmap` shows exactly same number of bytes with the `bitmap1`.

- How can I actually use the bitmap that has already been compressed?
- Is it possible to compress a bitmap and save the compressed one as a bitmap again?

Thanks for any comment.

Comment: a Bitmap is an uncompressed representation of an image.  If you want to upload the compressed image data, use File I/O to read it from storage as a byte array, or just use the `compressedData` that you already have

Comment: But the upload only accept bitmap but not byte array. I just want to make the bitmap smaller size without changing its height and width.

Comment: "upload only accept bitmap" - I find this very unlikely.  What is the signature of the upload method?

Comment: Bitmap _objects_ are always pure uncompressed data; otherwise you can't actually work with them. Compressed formats are purely for storage and transfer. So unless you can transfer it as byte array, the only effect of this code is degrading the image quality with jpeg compression artifacts.